# Bundling and distributing json file within extension to then read it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, flexsearch

I'm looking to add omnibox suggestions using flexsearch index which may be exported as files. I saw api for downloading a file, but I'd rather not have to host the index (also I dont want the hustle of copying data to non-user reachable environment). Is there some manifest field to require that json be included in extension bundle and api for reading it?

Comment: Simply include the file and then read it using `fetch('file.json')`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried simply importing json file from within js and that works. I believe what that means is that exported index would be stored in dist/js bundle.

Comment: Didn't test this, but its definitely worth a try as that's the simplest solution imaginable.